# How to show item icons on toolbar Android

Tags: android, xml, icons, toolbar

I am having some problems showing icons in the toolbar on Android It shows the string, but not the icon.

XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/bno_bookmark"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="@string/disable_draw"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_pen"
    android:showAsAction="always">
</item>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to add this to your menu xml

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

then `android:showAsAction="always"` should look like this

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

final output would be something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/bno_bookmark"
        android:visible="true"
        android:title="@string/disable_draw"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pen"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: Wonderful.  The icons were hidden under three dots, indicating overflow.  Your suggestion of adding "app:showAsAction="always"" worked perfectly.

Comment: Code working fine, the Icon take some space on the left of the Toolbar, is it possible to remove the space.

Comment: Cannot get this to work at all on android studio 2. Also android:layout_width and height is mandatory now.

Comment: @VansS what are you talking about, there is no height and width on menu items. you are obviously doing something very wrong and that is not a reason to downvote. this still work fine for me